# How to make an interaction b/w the C and the python files to copy the data?

Tags: python, c, ctypes

In this code, I am trying to copy the data from the first path to the second path and I am using `ctypes` to call the C file in `python`. I used `sprintf` and `snprintf` but the data was not copying. I also used `.so` and `.dll` files but nothing worked. Although when I run the code only in C, it copy the data. But when I run the code in `python`, it gives me the following error.

**Note: Don't suggest me to copy the data using `python` instead of `C`**

**Error**

```
hello_lib.transfer(ctypes.c_char_p("/home/bilal/Pictures/New"), ctypes.c_char_p("/home/bilal/Music"))
TypeError: bytes or integer address expected instead of str instance
```

**practice.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *transfer(char *f1, char *f2){
    char cmd[500];
    sprintf(cmd, "rsync -av %s %s", f1, f2);
    // snprintf(cmd, 500, "rsync -av %s %s", f1, f2);
    system(cmd);
}

int main(void){
    transfer("/home/bilal/Pictures/New", "/home/bilal/Music");
    return 0;
}
```

**practice.py**

```
from ctypes import cdll
from ctypes import c_char_p
import ctypes

hello_lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("/Path/to/practice.so")
# hello_lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("/Path/to/practice.dll")
hello_lib.transfer(ctypes.c_char_p("/home/bilal/Pictures/New"), ctypes.c_char_p("/home/bilal/Music"))
```

Comment: There is a chapter about [embedding and extending Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/index.html). Did you read it? Also, the [Python interpreter](https://www.python.org/downloads/source/) is open source, did you download and study its source code? At last your `rsync` command could be started from some Python code. On Linux you can use [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to understand the [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) done by your Python script

Comment: You are using Python to call a C function with ctypes that uses a system call to run rsync to copy data.  Why not just Python: `os.system(f'rsync -av {f1} {f2}')`.  This isn't "copying data with Python", it s just using a system call to run "rsync".  And just like the previous exact same question that was deleted, set `.argtypes` if you want to call the function correctly, and use byte strings (`b'path'`, not `'path'`).  That's what the `bytes address instead of str` error means.

Comment: @MarkTolonen How to use `.argtypes`? Could you please give me an example of it. Thanks!

Comment: @MarkTolonen I used `os.system`. Thanks! But I want to know `.argtypes`. I am new to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, your transfer() function declares `char*` as a return value, but doesn't return anything.  Change it to `void` and then use the following.

`.argtypes` declares the types of arguments, and `ctypes` uses it for checking that the number and type of parameters is correct.  Without it, it *might* work for some types but won't check that the types match.

`.restype` declares the return type.  Use `None` for `void`.

The `c_char_p` type requires byte strings, not Unicode strings.  Note the leading `b`.  You can also `.encode()` your Unicode strings to convert them to byte strings.  Use `wchar_t*` in C and `c_wchar_p` in Python to use Unicode strings, but then you'd need to call `wsystem()`.

```py
import ctypes as ct

hello_lib = ct.CDLL('/Path/to/practice.so')
hello_lib.transfer.argtypes = ct.c_char_p,ct.c_char_p
hello_lib.transfer.restype = None
hello_lib.transfer(b'/home/bilal/Pictures/New'),b'/home/bilal/Music')
```